# Deploy application in Tomcat excluding ROOT

Tags: java, xml, tomcat7, war

I'm trying to deploy a webapp (named prodPub.war) on Tomcat v7.0.57 and to avoid the creation of the ROOT exploded folder from the webapp.

I **already** know that I can rename the webapp as ROOT and I know **as well** that I can add the following configuration into the server.xml

```
<Host appBase="webapps" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false" deployOnStartup="false"> 

<Context path="" docBase="prodPub" debug="0" reloadable="true"></Context> 

</Host>
```

Unfortunately even if my webapp name is prodPub.war I continue to see just the ROOT folder exploded in the Tomcat webapps folder.

At this stage, I ended up with an usual workaround that consists in the creation of a ROOT.xml file in the ..\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost folder and to set its content in:

```
<Context docBase="prodPub" path="" reloadable="true" />
```

I obtained what I was looking for, in terms of exploded folders in Tomcat webapps, **but** I'm finding something weird on the tomcat startup logs

```
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\webapps\ROOT does not exist or is not a readable directory
        at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:5110)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5294)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:672)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1859)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Jan 19, 2016 5:37:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:672)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1859)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error in resourceStart()
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5295)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more

Jan 19, 2016 5:37:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:672)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1859)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

So, I was wondering if anybody here already tried this kind of approach (based on the ROOT.xml file) and what have you done with these logs? May I just simply ignore them?

Comment: check your root folder permissions

Comment: @Ghayel the root folder does not exist, because the webapps folder at deploy time would contain only prodPub.war and some other .war files, not ROOT folder, should the ROOT folder be created? if yes why?

Comment: what is your operating system? I mean windows or linux?